# I am using Azure AML and created training pipeline. tracking metrics like r2, mae available in "individual steps" but not in "job overview"

Tags: azure, pipeline, metrics, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure AML and created training pipeline. I am tracking metrics like r2, mae etc. Metrics are available in ind. steps but not as "Job Metrics"[image: Job Overview that does not have metrics]

[image: Evaluate model step has metrics]

Kindly help me track metrics at job level

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the Jobs tab.
2. Select either All experiments to view all the jobs in an experiment or select All jobs to view all the jobs submitted in the Workspace.

In the All jobs' page, you can filter the jobs list by tags, experiments, compute target and more to better organize and scope your work.

1. Make customizations to the page by selecting jobs to compare, adding charts or applying filters. These changes can be saved as a Custom View so you can easily return to your work. Users with workspace permissions can edit, or view the custom view. Also, share the custom view with team members for enhanced collaboration by selecting Share view.
2. To view the job logs, select a specific job and in the Outputs + logs tab, you can find diagnostic and error logs for your job.

Refer this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-track-monitor-analyze-runs#custom-view) for more information

Refer - https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/track-and-monitor-experiments/logging-api/logging-api.ipynb